# Talking about future

Tags: future-tense

Please compare the following two sentences.
１．I hope your father will get well.
２．I hope your father gets well.

I came to know that some/many native English speakers prefer Sentence 2 to Sentence 1.

I understand that you should use the auxiliary verb "will" when talking about the future. What is the logic of choosing Sentence 2? Are there any native English speakers who prefer Sentence 1?

Comment: If you "understand that you should use the auxiliary verb 'will' when talking about the future", then your understanding is incorrect, I'm afraid. The auxiliary verb _will_ may be used to refer to the future; but it is not the only way to do so. There are many others, and the simple present tense is one of the most common, especially in a subordinate clause. It is not "the future tense"; there is no future tense in English. No matter what the textbook says. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **hope** is quite flexible. It's typical to use the **present tense** with **hope** to give a **future meaning**.

- "I **hope** that you have a good time," for example.

This is just like **if** in the first conditional -

- "I'll call you **if** anything happens."

But it's also possible to use **will** in certain contexts.

- "I **hope** that you **will** be able to finish on time."

In almost all cases, the **will** could be replaced by the present tense with little or no difference in meaning, but it doesn't always work the other way round.

- "I hope that he has his passport with him." -

cannot always be changed to:

- "I hope that he will have his passport with him."

as the first one has both present and future meaning, but the second one can only have future meaning.

So **hope + the present tense** is rather more flexible than **hope + will**, but sometimes they mean the same thing.

Some more examples...

- "They **hope** that you **will** remember your promise"

is almost the same as:

- "They **hope** that you remember your promise", but -
- "I **hope** that you agree to the proposal" -

might mean that you've already seen or heard the proposal, but if someone says:

- "I **hope** that you **will** agree to the proposal" -

it is less likely that you've seen it already and perhaps the proposal may not have been made yet.

The present continuous can also be used with **hope** and here the difference between *present* and *future* is even stronger. If someone says:

- "I **hope** that you're thinking of me"...

it clearly means that they hope the person is thinking of them right now, but -

- "I **hope** that you **will** be thinking of me"

obviously refers to some time in the future.

So to sum up, it's probably better to use **hope + present tense**, as this is more flexible, and only ever use **hope + will** if you are very clear that your meaning is in the future.

Source: [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page4.shtml)

[Perfect-English-Grammar](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/hope.html)